# I need to prove that A is Lebesgue-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm struggling with this measure theory problem. It says:

> Let $B$ be a Lebesgue-measurable set, with $m(B)<\infty$ and
> $A\subset B$. Prove that $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable if and only if
> $m(B)=m$* $(A)+m$* $(B\backslash A)$. ($m$ is the measure application
> and $m$*$ $ the exterior measure application in $\Bbb R$).

The implication $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable $\longrightarrow$ $m(B)=m$* $(A)+m$* $(B\backslash A)$ is easy, because if $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable, then $m$* $(F)=m$* $(F\cap A)+m$* $(F\backslash A), \forall F\subseteq \Bbb R$.

I have problems with the reverse implication. The problem gives a hint: "you can use that, if $A\subseteq \Bbb R, m$* $(A)<\infty$, then $\exists B$ Lebesgue-measurable with $A\subseteq B$ that verifies $m(B)=m$* $(A)$".

Comment: $m^\ast(B\setminus A)=m(B)-m_\ast(A)$, if you can prove that relation using the hint, then you get that $m^\ast(A)=m_\ast(A)$.

Comment: But how do i use $m(A)$ in that expression? I can't use $m(A)$ till I prove that A is Lebesgue-measurable, that's my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the hint says, there exists $E$ measurable with $A\subset E$ and $m^*(A)=m(E)$. From this we get that we can replace $B$ by $B\cap E$ in
$$\tag1
m(B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B\cap A^c). 
$$
Indeed, 
$$\tag2
m(E)=m^*(A)\leq m(B\cap E)\leq m(E), 
$$
so $m(E)=m(B\cap E)$. Then
\begin{align}
m^*(A)+m^*(B\cap E\cap A^c)
&=m^*(A)+m^*(B\cap A^c\cap E)+m^*(B\cap A^c\cap E^c)\\[0.25cm]&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -m^*(B\cap A^c\cap E^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m^*(A)+m^*(B\cap A^c)-m^*(B\cap A^c\cap E^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m^*(B)-m^*(B\cap A^c\cap E^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m^*(B)-m^*(B\cap  E^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m(B\cap (B\cap E^c)^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m(B\cap E)=m^*(A). 
\end{align}

So we have $m^*(B\cap E\cap A^c)=0$.

Now,  for any $F$, \begin{align}
m^*(F\cap A)+m^*(F\cap A^c)
&\leq m^*(F\cap  B\cap E)+m^*(F\cap ((B\cap E)^c\cup (B\cap E)\setminus A) )\\[0.3cm]
&\leq m^*(F\cap  B\cap E)+m^*(F\cap (B\cap E)^c)+m^*(F\cap B\cap E\cap A^c)\\[0.3cm]
&\leq m^*(F\cap  B\cap E)+m^*(F\cap (B\cap E)^c)+m^*( B\cap E\cap A^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m^*(F\cap  B\cap E)+m^*(F\cap (B\cap E)^c)\\[0.3cm]
&=m^*(F).
\end{align}

Comment: But how do you know $m$* $(B\backslash A)=0$? Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer does not solve my problem. I can't suppose $m$* $(B\backslash A)=0$, and i need to prove that $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable if it verifies that $m$* $(B\backslash A)=m(B)-m$* $(A)$, with $A\subset B, B$ Lebesgue-measurable.

Comment: Ok, please see the edit.

Comment: I still don't get how do you come to the conclusion that $m^*(B\backslash A)=0$. You found that $m^*(A)+m^*(B\cap E\cap A^c)=m(B\cap E)$, and that means $m^*(B\cap E\cap A^c)=0$, but that does not mean that $m^*(B\backslash A)=0$ too. Am I wrong? There must be cases where $m^*(B\backslash A)\neq 0$. Thank you for your support!

Comment: The point is to use $B\cap E$, and $B\cap E\cap A^c$ is $(B\cap E)\setminus A$.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that just a particular case? There are cases where $m(B)>m^*(A)$, verifying $m^*(B\backslash A)\neq 0$, and you're not contemplating them. I think I can't extrapolate the conclusion i got from $B\cap E$ to $B$. Does your proof really work for any set $B$ like the one in the problem? Beacuse using $B\cap E$, it proves it for sets that verify that it's measure $m$ equals $m^*(A)$, not in general. Sorry if I'm just not getting it, I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: The $B$ at the end is not the $B$. Note that the original question has terrible phrasing, as $B$ is a fixed set at the beginning, but it is another set at the end (that I called $E$). The "$B$" I'm using at the end is $B\cap E$, not the original $B$. I have now replaced all the $B$ in the last computation with $B\cap E$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Note that now the last few lines look a lot more cumbersome because of all the $B\cap E$. It would be simpler to have $B$ instead... which is what I had done initially. Renaming something is fairly common to keep notation simpler; I suggest you keep it in mind going forward, as it will happen again in stuff you read.